# win32com not sending attachments

Tags: python, win32com

This is my first question, so I hope it is ok.

I am trying to send an email with an attachement with Python using win32com with Outlook 2010. And it sends the email. But it is not sending the attachment. I based my code in an example given here.

```
def email_tamplate(*args):
  Format = { 'UNSPECIFIED' : 0, 'PLAIN' : 1, 'HTML' : 2, 'RTF'  : 3}
  profile = "Outlook"
  #session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
  outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
  #session.Logon(profile)
  mainMsg = outlook.CreateItem(0)
  mainMsg.To = str(login_entry.get())+"@amazon.com"
  mainMsg.Subject = "Sauron personal report request between "+str(start_date.get())+" and "+str(end_date.get())
  mainMsg.BodyFormat = Format['RTF']
  mainMsg.HTMLBody = body

  try:
    attachment1= ('C:\\Users\\' + str(login_entry.get()) + '\\My Documents\\status_email.csv')
    mainMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
  except:
    pass                                   

  mainMsg.Send()
```

Here's the error message I get when not using the Try/except:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1475, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\alvaros\Dev\Sauron\v2\Sauron v2.2.1.py", line 478, in status_email
>       email_tamplate()
>     File "C:\Users\alvaros\Dev\Sauron\v2\Sauron v2.2.1.py", line 424, in email_tamplate
>       mainMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
>     File ">", line 3, in Add
>   pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', "You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation.", None, 0, -2147024891), None)

Everything works except that the attachment is not sent. The path of the attachment is correct and the file is there.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the try/except and see if you are getting an error. If you are, post the exception in the question.

Comment: I just did. Thank you.

Comment: If you add a line `print "attachment exists:", os.path.exists(attachment1)` does it print True? What if you try to attach a plain text file?

Comment: It doesn't print anything when entering that line. And it gives the same error when attaching a plain text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to run the program as Administrator or if that doesn't work, then[enter link description here][1] you may need to use "Extended MAPI" to get this to work:

- http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/227/284/

On the other hand, this thread talked about editing the properties of the PST file itself or editing its properties in the Windows registry:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0bb03637-7aec-42ce-97c9-12911b3b0305/outlook-2010-you-dont-have-appropriate-permission-to-perform-this-operation?forum=outlook

Comment: Thank you. I tried as an administrator and it gives me another error that the Server Execution Failed.
I also tried the Extended MAPI as stated in the link you provided. And still get the error: 
(-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, None)

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved already. 
Thank you for the help. 
It might have been an indent issue. Because it basically got solved by itself.